# SwiftData Model Inheriting from Codable Class

Tags: swift, codable, swift-data

I have a backend written in swift (hosted on GCP Cloud Run, aka linux so no access to Apple-specific frameworks).

I have a regular codable class:

```
open class MyClass: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var name: String

    init(id: String, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

That I share across the frontend and backend (via a swift package) thus allowing me to send that data from the backend to frontend easily by encoding the object on the backend and decoding the object on the frontend.

I now want to manage data on the frontend using SwiftData, but I can't seem to set this up properly.

How can I do this properly? Or if this isn't possible (I've heard inheritance and codable can cause issues with SwiftData) is there another approach I can take here?

**My Initial Attempt:**
My initial attempt was to just create a super class with the `@Model` macro:

```
@Model
class MyFrontendClass: MyClass { }
```

This then gives me the error:

```
@Model requires an initializer be provided for 'MyFrontendClass'
```

When I created a basic initializer that calls the other classes's initializer:

```
@Model
class MyFrontendClass: MyClass {
    override init(id: String, name: String) {
        super.init(id: id, name: name)
    }
}
```

I then get the error (inside the @Model macro's generated code):

```
'required' initializer 'init(from:)' must be provided by subclass of 'MyClass'
```

I've then tried adding that initializer:

```
@Model
class MyFrontendClass: MyClass {
    override init(id: String, name: String) {
        super.init(id: id, name: name)
    }
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }
}
```

At this point I get the error:

```
1. 'self' used in property access 'persistentBackingData' before 'super.init' call
2. 'super.init' isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer
```

in the `@Model` macro generated code:

```
required init(backingData: any SwiftData.BackingData<MyFrontendClass>) {

  self.persistentBackingData = backingData
}
```

Comment: SwiftData does not work well with Codable the only example Apple provides is with the usage of a convenience init for SwiftData https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/maintaining-a-local-copy-of-server-data

Comment: I don't think the @Model macro handles any kind of inheritance now. For the inheritance part you have some alternatives for MyClass, make it a separate model and create a 1-to-1 relationship between them, merge it by incorporating the properties into the subclass or make it a struct and use it as a custom type for a property in the subclass (maybe it can be a class, I haven't tested). If you only have 2 properties in the superclass I think I would go for the second option.

Comment: I don’t think that a model can inherit from another class which is not a model. It may be easier to define your codable class as @Model and setup the CodingKeys (SwiftData add _ at the end of attribute (if I make no mistake)